# Display number of records of a particular query in VB code

Tags: sql, vb.net, count, records

How do we use VB code to count the number of records for a particular Query or SQL statement ?

I have been working on this and have tried different ways and I haven't gotten it to show the correct record counts. This is my code, mycommand is a sql statement.

```
Dim mycommand As New SqlCommand("SELECT count(*)
    FROM ziBLE a INNER JOIN meBLE b ON a.ziLD = b.zp5
    WHERE ( b.ae" < "@ae 

    mycommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ae", ae_value) '

Dim count As Int16 = Convert.ToInt16(mycommand.ExecuteScalar())
            MsgBox(count.ToString())
```

or this code according to the below site ? But is giving me an error message that says result can't be an integer. Please advise.  Thank you

```
Dim result as Integer = ds1.Tables("Count").Rows.Count
```

http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?621729-RESOLVED-Trying-to-get-Row-count-from-SELECT-query

Answer (score 0):

You shoul try somthing like this:

```
     public Int32 name(int @a) 
        {
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(string);
            try
            {
                con.Open();
string sql = "SELECT count(*)FROM ziBLE a INNER JOIN meBLE b ON a.ziLD = b.zp5 WHERE ( b.ae" < "@ae)"
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con);
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@a", a);
                return Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());

            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex; 
            }
            finally
            {
                con.Close();
            }
        }
```

here it is an example in c# but you could try to converted to vb, I think that this should work fine, I recomend that you could made the query directly to the database and then in youre application call the scalar function you created in the db, but if you dont like the code youre db, try to couple the example to visual basic

Comment: Thanks for your code, I think is great, but do you have a simple code like this one below that is short and we don't need to write another SQL statement since I already wrote one but that works ?  Dim result as Integer = ds1.Tables("Count").Rows.Count

Answer (score 0):

You could make a scalar function in sql server like these:

```
Create Function <Function_name> (@a int)
Returns int
as
Begin
 Declare @b int;
 SELECT count(*)
 FROM ziBLE a INNER JOIN meBLE b ON a.ziLD = b.zp5
 WHERE b.ae" < "@ae
 Return @ret;
End
```

And then in the application you could write something like this:

```
Public Function Youre_function_name(ByVal @a as integer) as Integer
Dim result as Int32 = 0
Dim sql as string = "Select * From <Function_name> (@a)"
Using conn as SqlConnection(connstring)
Dim cmd as sqlcommand(sql,conn)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@a", a)
Try
 conn.Open()
 result = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar())
 conn.Close()
Catch ex as Exception
 Throw ex
End Try

Return result

End Function
```

I think its a much cleaner way to execute, and the result will be faster, because the query is executed by the database engine, it uses RAM memory that uses the database engine, remember that it was created for that (query execution), and the scalar result is the only data that will be sended to the application, instead off doing the whole process from the application, and afterwards you could analyze the execution plan to evaluate if you use (*), or instead use the primary key for the table to take advantage off the cluster index... take a look at these code and evaluate...

Comment: Nice code, very neat. But in my VB code I already have a similar SQL statement to sends only the query result into excel. I also have a function that depends on users selection it goes to the function with the query and sends it to excel. This means base on your code I have to put your function into another function. I also have to create like 6 functions then because I have 6 different query that I have to total the counts of. I still think this code Dim result as Integer = ds1.Tables("Count").Rows.Count is easier because I already have it loop Query unless this code doesn't work. Thx

Comment: Instead I just use this code (below) to count. It makes my code run longer because one loop to count the records and another to access the query records.  For Each row As DataRow In dataset.Tables(0).Rows cnt +=1 Next